# LiveScore BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse this site:

http://www.livescore.com/soccer/champions-league/

I'm looking to get the links for the rows with numbers:

```
FT  Zenit St. Petersburg    3 - 0   Standard Liege"
```

The 3 - 0 is a link a link; what I want to do is find every link with numbers (so not results like

```
 15:45  APOEL Nicosia   ? - ?   Paris Saint Germain
```

), so I can go load these links and parse out the minute data (`<td class="min">`)

Hi!!! Needs edited. Now I'm able to get the links. Like this:

```
import urllib2, re, bs4

sitioweb = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livescore.com/soccer/champions-league/').read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sitioweb)
href_tags = soup.find_all('a', {'class':"scorelink"})

links = []

for x in xrange(1, len(href_tags)):
    insert = href_tags[x].get("href");links.append(insert)

print links
```

Now my problem is the following: I want to write all this into a DB (like sqlite) with the number of minute in which a goal was made (this information I can get from the link I get) but this is possible only in the case that the goal count is not ? - ?, as there isn't any goal made.

I hope you can understand me...

Best regards and thanks a lot for your help,

Marco

Comment: So anything with a score, basically? Do you have any code we can already piggyback on?

Comment: Look I edited the post

Comment: Martijn's answer and mine answered your initial question, if you paid attention. This is an entirely different topic from the original question, which means it should be asked in a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

The following search matches only your links:

```
import re

links = soup.find_all('a', class_='scorelink', href=True,
                      text=re.compile('\d+ - \d+'))
```

The search is limited to:

- `<a>` tags
- with the class `scorelink`
- a non-empty `href` attribute
- and the link text containing two digits separated by a dash.

Extracting just the links is then trivial:

```
score_urls = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all(
                  'a', class_='scorelink', href=True, text=re.compile('\d+ - \d+'))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.livescore.com/soccer/champions-league/').content)
>>> [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a', class_='scorelink', href=True, text=re.compile('\d+ - \d+'))]
['/soccer/champions-league/group-e/cska-moscow-vs-manchester-city/1-1821202/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/zenit-st-petersburg-vs-standard-liege/1-1801440/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/apoel-nicosia-vs-aab/1-1801432/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/bate-borisov-vs-slovan-bratislava/1-1801436/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/celtic-vs-maribor/1-1801428/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/fc-porto-vs-lille/1-1801444/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/arsenal-vs-besiktas/1-1801438/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/athletic-bilbao-vs-ssc-napoli/1-1801446/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/bayer-leverkusen-vs-fc-koebenhavn/1-1801442/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/malmo-ff-vs-salzburg/1-1801430/', '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/pfc-ludogorets-razgrad-vs-steaua-bucuresti/1-1801434/']
>>> pprint(_)
['/soccer/champions-league/group-e/cska-moscow-vs-manchester-city/1-1821202/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/zenit-st-petersburg-vs-standard-liege/1-1801440/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/apoel-nicosia-vs-aab/1-1801432/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/bate-borisov-vs-slovan-bratislava/1-1801436/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/celtic-vs-maribor/1-1801428/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/fc-porto-vs-lille/1-1801444/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/arsenal-vs-besiktas/1-1801438/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/athletic-bilbao-vs-ssc-napoli/1-1801446/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/bayer-leverkusen-vs-fc-koebenhavn/1-1801442/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/malmo-ff-vs-salzburg/1-1801430/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/pfc-ludogorets-razgrad-vs-steaua-bucuresti/1-1801434/']
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy to do outside of `BeautifulSoup`. Just find all the links first, then, filter out the ones that return a `? - ?` text, then get the `href` attribute from each item in the sanitized list. See below.

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

In [2]: import requests as rq

In [3]: url = "http://www.livescore.com/soccer/champions-league/"

In [4]: r = rq.get(url)

In [5]: bs = bsoup(r.text)

In [6]: links = bs.find_all("a", class_="scorelink")

In [7]: links
Out[7]: 
[<a class="scorelink" href="/soccer/champions-league/group-a/atletico-madrid-vs-malmo-ff/1-1821150/" onclick="return false;">? - ?</a>,
 <a class="scorelink" href="/soccer/champions-league/group-a/olympiakos-vs-juventus/1-1821151/" onclick="return false;">? - ?</a>,
...

In [8]: links_clean = [link for link in links if link.get_text() != "? - ?"]

In [9]: links_clean
Out[9]: 
[<a class="scorelink" href="/soccer/champions-league/group-e/cska-moscow-vs-manchester-city/1-1821202/" onclick="return false;">0 - 1</a>,
 <a class="scorelink" href="/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/zenit-st-petersburg-vs-standard-liege/1-1801440/" onclick="return false;">3 - 0</a>,
...

In [10]: links_final = [link["href"] for link in links_clean]

In [11]: links_final
Out[11]: 
['/soccer/champions-league/group-e/cska-moscow-vs-manchester-city/1-1821202/',
 '/soccer/champions-league/qualifying-round/zenit-st-petersburg-vs-standard-liege/1-1801440/',
...
```

Extracting the minutes from each link is, of course, up to you.